# Remove multiple parts of url with htaccess

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

How will be remove keyword that is occurring multiple times in the URL . like "-folder" in example below:
http://www.example.com/simple-folder/simple-folder-abcpage

I want to remove "-folder" that is two times in the above URL
Final result should be:
http://www.example.com/simple/simple-abcpage

-Muhammad Umair

Comment: I have tried this code `RewriteRule ^simple-folder(.*)$ /simple/$1 [L,R]` but  result of this is: 
http://www.example.com/simple/simple-folder-abcpage
where only one part removed

Comment: Is word simple always there?

Comment: yes, I just want to remove "-folder"

Comment: It will always be "simple-folder"  and I want to change it to "simple"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this rule as your very first rule in root .htaccess:

```
RedirectMatch 301 ^/simple-folder/simple-folder(.*)$ /simple/simple$1
```

Make sure there is no .htaccess in `/simple-folder/` folder.

Comment: Yes, it is funny that I have overlooked such a simple thing. 
Thanks #anubhava